# Horizontal/Column view explorer in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Explorer view in VS Code is showing in tree form (vertical expand/collapse). I have big monorepo which is difficult to navigate by expanding and collapsing all the time.

Instead I would like to view in horizontal form **similar to how MAC finder has column view**.

I will move this (explorer/other_extension) to bottom panel right next to terminal so that I have enough space to navigate the files.